# Сервер в приложении React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, потоки-данных

Есть приложение на React'e. Есть трансляция с IP камеры по протоколу rstp. Надо эту трансляцию вывести в браузер. Пишут, что для этого нужен сервер и подходит, например, библиотека 'node-rtsp-stream'.

Но как в существующее приложение на React'e добавить этот сервер - где его сохранить, какое расширение?

Comment: Сервер - это сервер. React-приложение - это клиент. Не надо путать) Реакт похватит лишь данные и выведет с этого сервера. Собственно, пакет, который Вы указываете, ставится на Node.js на сервере. Инструкция в самом пакете есть))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Скрипт ffmpeg вынимает трансляцию, разбивает на фрагменты.tx, создаёт плейлист.m3u8, удаляет фрагменты старше 'n' секунд чтобы папка не перегружалась.
2. Юзер нажимает кнопку (фронтенд), дёргается скрипт в контроллере, п.1 начинает выполняться.
3. Плеер проигрывает фрагменты из локальной папки.
4. Задержка неизбежна ибо это hls.